# Unable to pass struct pointer to function inside a function in C

Tags: c

**The problem is:**

**Edit:** So, how can I point the GLFWwindow *window pointer from main, to CreateWindow() function, where glfwCreateWindow() function returns a pointer to the original pointer in main()?

Calling the function CreateWindow is causing unexpected results. After function call, original *window struct is NULL and a segmentation fault occurs.

**This is the main:**

```
int main() {
clear();    
GLFWwindow *window;

CreateWindow(window, 800, 600);
assert(window != NULL);
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
}
DestroyWindow(window);
return 0;}
```

**This is the called function:**

```
void CreateWindow(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height) {
if(!glfwInit()){
    printf("Unable to init glfw!");
}
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height,"Vulkan",NULL,NULL);
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, window);};
```

**This here is the result:**

test: engine_core.c:28: main: Assertion `window != NULL' failed.

[1]    3248 abort (core dumped)  ./test

Comment: Please point me to the answer.

Comment: Did you see the answers in the linked question?

Comment: Yep, saw the answer. I understand that I need to a pointer to pointer, but I have exhausted how it works in this case. GLFWwindow *window has to be a pointer, because the return function from glfwCreateWindow() is casting the return to a pointer. How can I point the pointer from main() to CreateWindow() function, so that glfwCreateWindow() function can return a pointer that points all the way back to main()?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. What do you mean?

Comment: Does it make any sense after edit?

Comment: Not really. Where do you see a cast?

Comment: I think your edit matches exactly what I gave previously in the answer.

Comment: The function call inside CreateWindow() --> window = glfwCreateWindow() returns a cast... || return (GLFWwindow*) window;

Comment: which cast? where? Did you show us the `CreateWindow()` you actually use?

Comment: @prog-fh you are correct. I understand the first option, but I would like to also understand how the second option is achieved. I see the logic, but can't type the code. I don't use any casts. The CreateWindow() I show is the one I use. The cast comes from GLFW.h library.

Comment: read it in my answer. I just wrote it (reload the page in your browser if you can't see it right now)

Comment: Thanks!! I understand the logic behind this. And I think that option 1 is better too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1) `CreateWindow()` could **return** the window pointer.

2) `CreateWindow()` could expect `GLFWindow **`

In the second case, you should pass `&window` as argument (from `main()`), and use `*window` in the definition of `CreateWindow()`. This will change the `window` pointer in the calling context (`main()`).

The first option is easier (my own opinion).

---

1)

```
GLFWwindow * CreateWindow(int width, int height) {
if(!glfwInit()){
    printf("Unable to init glfw!");
}
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height,"Vulkan",NULL,NULL);
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, window);
return window;
}
```

Then in `main()`

```
GLFWwindow *window=CreateWindow(800, 600);
```

---

2)

```
void CreateWindow(GLFWwindow **window, int width, int height) {
if(!glfwInit()){
    printf("Unable to init glfw!");
}
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
*window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height,"Vulkan",NULL,NULL);
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(*window, *window);
}
```

Then in `main()`

```
GLFWwindow *window;
CreateWindow(&window, 800, 600);
```

Comment: engine_core.c:25:13: error: storage size of ‘window’ isn’t known
  GLFWwindow window;

Comment: So this approach does not work. It has to be declared as a pointer.

Comment: @leafy_fingers sorry, I didn't read well your `CreateWindow()` function. I changed the answer.

Comment: core_window.h:5:31: note: expected ‘GLFWwindow *’ {aka ‘struct GLFWwindow *’} but argument is of type ‘GLFWwindow **’ {aka ‘struct GLFWwindow **’}
 void CreateWindow(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height);

Comment: I spied the code and GLFWwindow has to be pointer, because the return from glfwCreateWindow() function is casting the return to pointer.

Comment: @leafy_fingers You didn't change the declaration of `CreateWindow`.

Comment: @leafy_fingers focus on the first option, it's much more straightforward (no multiple stars...)

Comment: Thanks!! I understand the logic behind this. And I think that option 1 is better too!